# Как можно сравнить очень большие целые числа, записанные в файле в Free Pascal?

Tags: файлы, pascal, сравнение, числа, freepascal

Как можно сравнить очень большие целые числа, записанные в файле в Free Pascal? Пусть у нас есть какое-то число чисел, записанных в файл. Будем их разделять через EOF. Конец строки через EOL. То как нам сравнить эти числа? Ну и для наглядности, давайте запишем их в порядке убывания. Подкиньте идеи для реализации, а если еще будут скрипты какие-то, то будет вообще круто. Хочу разобраться с этими файлами xD. 
У меня такая идея (но что-то она плохо реализуется). 
Если мы записываем в память первое число в виде массива из char. Пусть первый элемент это a[x] последний a[z] этого числа. Запомним  х и z: a:=x, b:=z.Читаем второе число, пусть первый элемент - a[x+1], а второй - a[y] (x+1, так как eof тоже занимает место). Если z-xy-x-1, тогда ничего не делаем. Но получается так, что надо сравнивать всегда каждый элемент массивов, так как могут быть числа 001 и 2, и по моему первому сравнению уже будет ошибка.
Вот я думаю так сравнивать, только надо придумать, чтобы вначале числа нули отбрасывались. Можно как-то лучше описать это?

```
 x := 1;
   Reset(File1);
   While Not eof(File1) do
   Begin
      Read(File1, num[i]);
      Inc(i)
   End;
   z := i;
   j := z + 1;
   While Not eof(File1) do
   Begin
      Read(File1, num[j]);
      Inc(j)
   End;
   y := j;
   If j > i Then a := 1 Else If j = i Then
   Begin
      While z <> x do
      Begin
         If  Ord(num[j]) > Ord(num[i]) Then a := 1 Else If Ord(num[j]) < Ord(num[i]) Then a := 0;
         Dec(j);
         Dec(i)
      End;
   End Else a := 0;
   If a = 1 Then
   Begin
      x := z+1;
      z := y
   End;
```

Comment: То как нам сравнить эти числа? - справа налево ( или с конца к началу :) ).

Comment: Как сравнивать не имеет смысла. Я просто хочу понять сам процесс сравнения чисел.

Comment: "Как сравнивать не имеет смысла." - эта фраза не имеет смысла.

Comment: Нужен скрипт сравнения больших чисел из файла

Answer (score 2):

Последовательность действий для сравнения больших чисел, не вмещающихся в `longint`:

1. Записываете 2 числа в две строки.
2. Проверяете первые символы на знаки. Если, например, первый символ у первого числа - минус, а у второго - цифра, то значит второе число больше.
3. Проверяете каждую строку на наличие незначащих нулей, находите индекс первого вхождения числа, отличающегося от 0
4. Проверяете размеры двух строк, если какая-то из строк имеет больший размер, значит это число больше и алгоритм на этом шаге заканчивается (учитывая третий шаг).
5. Проверяете первые символы, начиная с индекса шага 3 в двух строках (переведя их в числовой формат из таблицы ASCIII), если какое-то из этих чисел окажется большим, то оно окажется большим и алгоритм на этом шаге заканчивается.
6. Такая сверка проводится с каждым вплоть до последнего элемента.

Comment: Да, но как же быть с отрицательными числами и незначащими нулями?

Comment: @0xdb делать проверки. думаю автор разберется. саму суть я рассказал

Comment: Ну да, пождомдём мнения автора. Последний раз он заходил не так давно, в декабре 17-го. Апнул, чтобы скрасить ожидание.